# Google App Engine (So "Pure Python"): Convert PDF to Image

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, python-imaging-library, ghostscript

In Google App Engine, I need to be able to take an uploaded PDF and convert it to an image (or maybe one day a number of tiled images) for storing and serving back out.  Is there a library that will read PDF files that is also 100% python (so it can be uploaded with my app)?

From what I've gathered so far...

- *PIL* does not **read** PDF files, only writes them.
- *GhostScript* is the standard FOSS PDF reader, but I don't believe I'll be able to upload it with my app to GAE since I don't believe it's 100% python.

Is there anything else I might be able to use?  Or maybe even a web service that I can call?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look into using the GAE Conversion API (not yet fully released). There's a [tester signup form here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEtMTTVKN0Rrd0RyNlc2VkFCaXRlZHc6MQ&ndplr=1), with a link to further details.

From the doc:

Conversions can be performed in any direction between PDF, HTML, TXT, and image formats, and OCR will be employed if necessary. Note that while PNG, GIF, JPEG, and BMP image formats are supported as input formats, only PNG is available for output.

Comment: Hey awesome!  Thanks.  I'll definitely sign up for that.  Looks like the most straightforward solution around (once it comes out).

Comment: Looks like the Conversion API is now [discontinued as of Nov 12](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview)